# Integral limits in frac command

Tags: fractions, integral

I am trying to display the fraction of two integrals as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
E_{sym} = \frac{\iint\displaylimits_{A_{sym}}\sqrt{(u + u_r)^2 + (v + v_r)^2 + (w - w_r)^2}dA}{{\iint\displaylimits_{A_{sym}}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + w^2} dA}},
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The problem is that in the frac command the lower limit on the double integrals appear next to the double integral signs, instead of below them. Outside the frac command this does not seem to be a problem:

```
\begin{equation}
E_{sym} = \iint\displaylimits_{A_{sym}}\sqrt{(u + u_r)^2 + (v + v_r)^2 + (w - w_r)^2}dA/{\iint\displaylimits_{A_{sym}}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + w^2} dA},
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much,

Louis

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\limits`, if you want to force the limits below; `\displaylimits` does it only in display style (which does not apply to numerator and denominator of fractions). You should probably have `E_{\mathrm{sym}}` rather than `E_{sym}` (the same for `A`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by comment.